# get Json Key based on Json Value of an Object which resides in an Json Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

How to get key of a json which resides within a array based on value, say if the value as **ValueB** it should return **MainB**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ArrayController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.myDatas =  [
      {
        "Test1": "Value1",
        "MainA": ""
      },
      {
        "Test1": "Value2",
        "MainA": "ValueB"
      },
      {
        "Test1": "",
        "MainA": "ValueC"
      }
    ];

    $scope.getJsonKey = function(jsonArray, jsonValue) 
    {
        angular.forEach(jsonArray, function(value, index) 
        {
            if (value.Test1 === jsonValue) 
            {
                return "Test1";
            }
            if (value.MainA === jsonValue) 
            {
                return "MainA";
            }
        });
    };
   console.log($scope.getJsonKey($scope.myDatas, "ValueB"));

});
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Comment: Can you share the code you have written so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small function that should do what you want, as long as the values are unique:

```js
var arr=[
      {
        "Test1": "Value1",
        "MainA": "ValueA"
      },
      {
        "Test2": "Value2",
        "MainB": "ValueB"
      },
      {
        "Test3": "Value3",
        "MainC": "ValueC"
      }
    ]


function getKey(arr, val){
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        var item= arr[i];
        for(var key in item){
            if(val === item[key]) return key;
        }
    }   
    return null; // not found
}

console.log(getKey(arr, 'ValueB')) // MainB
```

Comment: @AlexMan should be the same, just send `$scope.myDatas` instead of arr

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$scope.getJsonKey = function(jsonArray, jsonValue) 
    {
        angular.forEach(jsonArray, function(value, index) 
        {
           for(var key in value) {

            if (value === jsonValue) 
            {
                return key
            }

            }
        });
    };
       console.log($scope.getJsonKey($scope.myDatas, "ValueB"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shared too much code here, so I'm not sure what the best solution would be.
However, to simply answer you question, you could use this example:
Convert JSON to a js object via $.parseJSON(), and then find your key:

```
function getKeyInArray(arr, val){
    for(var i=0, len=arr.length;i<len;i++){
        var obj = arr[i];
        for(var key in obj){
            if(obj[key] == val)
                return key;      
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

view example:
http://jsfiddle.net/wc3mhg8u/21/

Comment: Haha, seems like juvian beat me to it.